# Why am I getting error: TypeError: unsuppouted operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, processing

I am trying to make a list of grades and calculate the averages for each of the marks. The first line contains an "out of" list which is the total for each "test". Each following line in the original list has a student number and then a score that they got on each respective test. So far I have been able to calculate the mark each student has received on each test but I have having trouble adding the "n"th item in each list and dividing it by the number of marks to get the average for each test. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import urllib2

#Global Variables
marks = []

def setup():
    background(255)
    global marks
    calculateAverages(read_marks())
    read_marks()

def read_marks():
    global marks
    infile = urllib2.urlopen("http://cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/marks110.txt")

    count = 0
    for line in infile:
        line = line[:-1]
        data = line.split("\t")
        if count == 0:
            for i in range(len(data)-1):
                data[i] = int(data[i])
            count = 1
        else:
            for i in range(1, len(data)):
                data[i] = float(data[i])
                data[i] = data[i]*100/marks[0][i-1]

        marks.append(data)

    return marks

def calculateAverages(marks_list):
    print marks_list
    average_list = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, len(marks_list[0])):
        for j in range(len(marks_list)):
            sum += marks[j][i]
        average = sum/len(marks_list)

        average_list.append(average)

    print average_list
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Always post **the whole error message** with **full traceback** please.

Comment: You are trying to perform addition (`+`) on `float` and `str`. Somewhere in your code you do not convert parsed numbers (as string) into actual numbers (float/int). Probably the error stems from `sum += marks[j][i]`, where you could change `marks[j][i]` into `int(marks[j][i])`

Comment: Find what line is giving you the error and add int() or str()  (depending on what you want) to the values.

Comment: Seeing all those global variables, and functions which are run once and return nothing, is painful. No context managers either. Is that Python 2?!

Comment: You want `range(len(data))`, not `range(len(data) - 1)`. `range(n)` already generates the values 0 through `n - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I would make changes to the rest of the code, all of your issues are within `calculateAverages(marks_list)`, at least for this question.

There are a few issues going on in your code. First I'll touch on the error message you're seeing:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'str'`

This exception is raised on your line `sum += marks[j][i]` because you are trying to add the first line to the sums. To fix this, you need to skip the first element in `marks_list`:

```
def calculateAverages(marks_list):
    ...
    for i in range(1, len(marks_list[0])):
        for j in range(1, len(marks_list)):
           ...
```

Also, the line that was throwing the error (`sum += marks[j][i]`) really *should* be looking at `marks_list` instead:

`sum += marks_list[j][i]`

I'll also take this opportunity to point out a mistake in your averaging. You are setting the running total `sum` to `0` before looping through *any* of the columns in `marks_list`, when you should be resetting it to `0` before *each* column.

Putting together the changes I've described for `calculateAverages(marks_list)`:

```
def calculateAverages(marks_list):
    print marks_list
    average_list = []
    for i in range(1, len(marks_list[0])):
        sum = 0
        for j in range(1, len(marks_list)):
            sum += marks_list[j][i]
        average = sum/len(marks_list)
        average_list.append(average)

    print average_list
```